# Django one-to-many forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Let's assume I have two models: A and B. A has one-to-many relationship with B i.e. an A can have many B's. If I configure admin properly I can see B's that belong to A and add them dynamically, without refreshing the website. I have an 'Add More' button and I can create many B's within some A. Now I'm looking for example of doing the same thing using standard views and templates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well... the [django admin source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin) might be a place to start. But what you're asking is non-trivial, you're going to end up writing a good chunk of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out you would need to create an inline formset for your view. The JS used in the admin is based on this project: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset . It hasn't seen many updates recently but there are examples and some usage docs here: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing really special about what the admin does with inlines (models you edit from change form of another models). It just uses Django's [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) and a bit of javascript to duplicate the actual HTML form. Django's formsets are built to handle an ambiguous amount of forms, so that's really all there is to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [**inline formset**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), and a bit of javascript probably for the 'add more' button.